# Passing in parameters to torndb.query()

Tags: python, mysql, formatting, tornado

I have the database connection set up in python using torndb.

I'm having issues trying to query it using `torndb.query(query, *parameters, **kwargs)`

```
query = """
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE name LIKE "%s"
AND score LIKE "%s"
"""

parameters = ["Jack", "A"]
students = db.query(query, parameters)
```

Although this query doesn't return anything even though there are matches in the mySQL database when running the raw query directly ->

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE name LIKE "Jack"
AND score LIKE "A
```

I would like to figure out how to make this query work using the `parameters` arg in the `torndb.query()` function, I know you can do this by formatting the actual query string but this is not my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query()` takes one argument for each `%s` in the query string:

```
db.query(query, "Jack", "A")
```

You're passing them as a single list object. To have Python expand the list into separate parameters, put an asterisk before it:

```
db.query(query, *parameters)
```